# Как правильно синхронизировать / Обновить данные на вебстранице (Html / JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

есть вебстраница, на ней textbox (или input) куда человек вводит данные.

Как сделать чтобы:
Когда пользователь вводит туда любое значение или слово, это отобразилось на 2й вкладке в браузере (как бы синхронно)

(т.е например как google doc, 2 человека находятся в документе кто-то его редактирует и второму сразу видно что пишет первый)

Comment: это "домашка"? точно вкладки? (пример с гуглдокс намекает на сетевое а это другой вопрос)

Comment: если вкладки - поищи по сайту, был такой вопрос